# How to import moment.js lib in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I downloaded moment.js in folder `lib`

In js file I trying to load like that:

```
var moment = require('../lib/moment'); // require
```

But In the console I see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
<anonymous> file:///Users/pizhev/Projects/web/js/chart.js:2
```

What is the correct way to import and use ?

When I trying to import like that:

```
import moment from '../lib/moment';
```

I see error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Comment: You haven't said so, but the error messages imply you are writing code to run in a browser. Have you tried [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/)?

Comment: Can you share a full code snippet in a code sandbox link so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @DrewGallagher — The code provided is enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Quentin we don't know if they are using the library in a ES6+ app or vanilla js so we cannot figure out the root cause as easily. Could just be the wrong import type for the project

Comment: @DrewGallagher — That information isn't code though. (and the error message reporting that the error is at `file:///Users/pizhev/Projects/web/js/chart.js:2
` makes it pretty clear its just a `<script>` in an HTML document)

Comment: I use vanilla js

Comment: Are you use to load your js in this style? `<script type="module" src="your-script-name.js"></script>`. With the `type="module"`

Comment: I just import in the html file and everything is fine..

Comment: @MaikLowrey — No, if they did that then they wouldn't get the second error. But they don't need to do that. They should follow the instructions in the documentation I linked to in my initial comment.

Comment: @BenJohnson if you are using a node project or ES6 js project then using require or import is fine. Otherwise you have to use the CDN link in a <script> tag

Comment: @DrewGallagher — They aren't using Node.js. Using ES6 doesn't allow `require`. Using ES6 alone isn't sufficient for `import` to work (and using `import` causes them to be using ES6 if they aren't already). They can link to moment.js in a `<script>` without using a CDN.